# Setting a JButton in a JTable cell, without renderer

Tags: java, swing

the problem i am facing is the following. I am doing a little Java project and i need to display a JTable of Strings with the last column being a JButton. I read the existing solutions but none suit my needs. The thing is that i already got my JButton with a preassigned controller and everything, so i don't want to add other classes or anything.

What i want is my JButton, who is already correctly prepared, to be display in the JTable.
If that is not possible I would like to know if there is a way to display a JButton not in a JTable cell but next to the last cell of every row.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you would like to see the code to get a better idea i can give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really possible... It would require... I don't even know. I don't think its possible

The problem is that Swing components (like JTable) don't actually contain other components. They use a Renderer to render the graphics of the table, but there's no plumbing for events like button clicks.

You'd be better off using a regular JPanel with a GridLayout or a GridBagLayout if you need this functionality

Comment: 1. JTable with one column for this purpose, this JPanel with JComponent(s) 2. `JButton with a preassigned controller and everything` == Swing Action/settable, scalable bean.Eventhandler

Comment: Thank you for your advice ControlAltDel, I just wanted to let you know that i ended up using a GridBagLayout as you suggested with Borders to do a custom JTable. Thank you very much again for taking the time to answer me.